# Convert hex to double with a given floating-point format in java

Tags: java, floating-point, binary, hex, double

I have a String representing a HEX value of a 64bit integer "0000000000EA6484". I need to transform it to the double value "0.9155962467" using Java. The instructions I 've been given is to format a 12.52 FP value of type int64_t (8 Bytes).

I found with some googling that the [int64_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) datatype in C++ is a signed integer. I have also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539733/64-bit-hex-conversion-to-decimal) which seem to be relevant but confused me a bit.

Finally I have tried the following java code to see if I get the expected result but I get in both cases "7.5894195E-317". I am sure that either I have not understood how to solve the problem so I would appreciate some help, or that the expected output is wrong.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String hexString = "0000000000EA6484";//0.9155962467

    long longValue = Long.parseLong(hexString, 16);
    longValue = Long.parseUnsignedLong(hexString, 16);
    System.out.println(longValue);

    double doubleValue = Double.longBitsToDouble(longValue);
    System.out.println(doubleValue);

    byte[] bytes = hexStringToByteArray(hexString);
    doubleValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getDouble();
    System.out.println(doubleValue);
}
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
}
```

Comment: Your instructions are inadequate. Your hex digits don't correspond to any IEEE 754 format. You will need to find out what they are, and what the conversion required is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown, `0000000000EA6484` represents 0.9155962467193603515625 in a Q40.24 format, not a floating-point format. This is a fixed-point format with 40 integer bits (including a sign bit) and 24 fraction bits. To convert it from the integer represented by those bits in a 64-bit integer format to the value represented by the same bits in the Q12.52 format, divide it by 2<sup>24</sup>: EA6484<sub>16</sub> = 15361156<sub>10</sub>, 15361156 / 2<sup>24</sup> = 0.9155962467193603515625. In Java, dividing the integer value by 16777216 (2<sup>24</sup>) should suffice.

It appears whomever told you this was a 12.52 FP format was wrong. Even if there is some endian issue, or any other byte reordering, that would not explain the shifted position of the bits with respect to a 12.52 format, since it differs by a sub-byte fraction (52 bits − 24 bits = 28 bits, which is 3½ bytes).

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Out of curiosity. How did you figure it out? Trial and error?

Comment: @ThanosFisherman: I simply converted the 0.9155962467 given in the question to binary to match them with bits in the hex string, figuring this could reveal which bits encoded the significand of a floating-point representation. It revealed a complete match. (If there had been a floating-point representation, I would have expected some unmatched bits for an exponent field. Hypothetically, there could be an unbiased exponent of zero in there, but not not see a clean way to make that match the purported 12.52 format. For this, the significand would include a leading 1, unusual for floating-point.)